how to avoid overlap between different black dots
I want to draw several black dots within a circular area. The requirements are:
The radii of the black dots should be random.
There should be no overlap between the different black dots.
The sizes of the black dots should be visibly different.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw circle (3cm); 
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} 
\foreach \i in {1,...,50} {
    \pgfmathparse{rand*0.3 + 0.1} 
    \let\radius=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{rand*360} 
    \let\angle=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{3 * \radius * cos(\angle)} 
    \let\x=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{3 * \radius * sin(\angle)} 
    \let\y=\pgfmathresult
    \node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=2*\radius cm] at (\x,\y) {}; 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Please add to your question, what’s wrong or insufficient with your code. Thank you // If you have a restriction, you must impose a restriction, like closing available subsegments.

A simple way to impose a „restriction“ is using random integers for angles and radii. This is like dividing your circle into discrete parts. Even if you draw the same place multiple times, it will appear as one, hence kind of restricted.

I'm  thinking along the lines of appending the x, y and radius valuesto separate lists, and comparing to all previous ones on every iteration. I have a non-working attempt which shows this, would it be okay to post it, albeit incomplete?

This was my attempt using TikZ:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle[radius=3];

\foreach[count=\c from 0] \i in {1,...,50} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{abs(rnd)*0.3 + 0.1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{rnd * 3 * cos(rnd*360)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{rnd * 3 * sin(rnd*360)}

    \ifnum\c=0
        \fill (\x,\y) circle[radius=\radius];
        \xdef\prevlist{\x/\y/\radius}
    \else
        \pgfmathsetmacro\validtest{1}
        \global\let\isvalid\validtest
        \foreach \xprev/\yprev/\rprev in \prevlist {
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\dist}{sqrt((\x-\xprev)^2 + (\y-\yprev)^2)}
            \pgfmathparse{\dist < (\radius + \rprev)}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                \pgfmathsetmacro\validtesttwo{0}
                \global\let\isvalid\validtesttwo
            \fi
        }
        \pgfmathsetmacro\myisvalid{\isvalid}
        \ifnum\myisvalid=1
            \fill (\x,\y) circle[radius=\radius];
            \xdef\prevlist{\prevlist,\x/\y/\radius}
        \fi
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Another version, in Python: (Credit: Help  from AI)
import numpy as np
import subprocess

with open("TeX_File.tex", "w") as f:
    f.write(
        r"""
        \documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick] (0,0) circle[radius=3];
        """
    )
    xlist = []
    ylist = []
    rlist = []
    for i in range(50):  # Increased iterations to increase chances of valid placements
        radius = np.random.rand() * 0.3 + 0.1
        angle = np.random.rand() * 2 * np.pi
        distance = np.random.rand() * (3 - radius)
        x = distance * np.cos(angle)
        y = distance * np.sin(angle)
        isvalid = True
        for j in range(len(xlist)):
            dist = np.sqrt((x - xlist[j])**2 + (y - ylist[j])**2)
            if dist < radius + rlist[j]:
                isvalid = False
                break
        if isvalid:
            f.write(f"\\fill ({x},{y}) circle[radius={radius}];\n")
            xlist.append(x)
            ylist.append(y)
            rlist.append(radius)
    f.write(
        r"""
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{document}
        """
    )
subprocess.run(['lualatex', "TeX_File.tex"])



Why failed? Isn't it the desired output?

@jlab the pure tikz solution was having problems with updating and checking values. the python solution is correct

thank you very much.

You need only one list, with format: x1/y1/r1,x2/y2/r2.... I took the liberty to fix it in your answer. It works well (much faster and better than my own try).

@jlab thank you for fixing that!

Maybe you could try a graph with the force library and its spring electrical layout. It allows to place the nodes as electric charges that repulse each other.
Example (be patient at compilation,it takes some times):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary {force}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every edge/.style={draw=none},
  ]
  \graph [
    random seed=14,
    spring electrical layout,
    nodes={draw, fill=black,circle, as={},inner sep=0pt},
    clique,
  ]
  {
    \foreach \i in {1,...,50} {
      \i [
        grow=\fpeval{randint(-180,180)},
        minimum size=\fpeval{3*rand() +1} mm,
        electric charge=\fpeval{rand()+0.1}
      ],
    }
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


I use clique, so that each node is connected to each others. The node setting
grow=\fpeval{randint(-180,180)},

isn't really necessary, but the dispersion seems more random to me with it.

thank you very much.It's very close to what I was thinking.
